# `Not Found (HTTP 404)` error when using `genius` package to get lyrics

Tags: r, genius-api

I create a [dataset](https://github.com/jubyshu/tidydata/blob/master/data/beatles_original_songs.csv) that contains all the original songs of Beatles. And I want to get the lyrics of all the songs using `genius` package. I use the following code to get lyrics but throw an error.

```r
map(beatles_songs$song, ~ genius_lyrics("The Beatles", ., "simple"))
```

```
Error in read_xml.response(x$response, ..., as_html = as_html) : 
  Not Found (HTTP 404).
In addition: Warning message:
In request_GET(session, url) : Not Found (HTTP 404).
```

I think maybe this is because the names of songs in the list don't match the songs in genius.com, but I don't know how to check it. So what should I do to get lyrics of all the songs at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `purrr` package has a number functions that handle warnings and errors.  I'd suggest something like the following, inspired by [this example](https://www.hvitfeldt.me/blog/purrr-tips-and-tricks/#safely-compact):

```
genius_lyrics_s <- safely(genius::genius_lyrics)

beatles_songs <- tibble(song = c("Mr. Moonlight", "She Loves You", "Under my Thumb", "Octopus's Garden"))
map(beatles_songs$song, ~ genius_lyrics_s("The Beatles", ., "simple")) %>% 
map("result") %>%
  compact()
```

Comment: This definitely will work but the desired way to do the above would be to use the `add_genius()` function

Answer (score 0):

In your case the best way to get song results would be to use `add_genius()`.

```
beatles %>%
  add_genius("The Beatles", song)
```

The genius package has the functions `possible_lyrics()` and `possible_album()` for just this reason. Try that out next time!